# I want to create a Scrollbar by creating a frame in a canvas widget, but the bar don't show up

Tags: python, tkinter

According to some answers in Stack Overflow, I create a scrollbar by creating a canvas and embed frame into the canvas, but after I do that, I can only click *arrow* in scrollbar to scroll the window, but the bar don't show up, whatever I shrink the window or create many widgets in frame.

```
class Basic_frame:
    def __init__(self):
        root.unbind('<Configure>')
        self.frame_canvas = Canvas(
            root, width=i_window_width, height=i_window_height, bg='red')
        self.window_frame = Frame(
            self.frame_canvas)
        self.xscrollbar = Scrollbar(
            self.frame_canvas, orient='horizontal', command=self.frame_canvas.xview)
        self.yscrollbar = Scrollbar(
            self.frame_canvas, orient='vertical', command=self.frame_canvas.yview)
        self.frame_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)
        self.frame_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set)

        self.frame_canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.frame_canvas.yview_moveto(0)
        self.yscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.xscrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        self.frame_canvas.create_window(
            (0, 0), window=self.window_frame, anchor='nw')
        # self.window_frame.bind('<Configure>', self.scroll_function)
        self.frame_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
        self.frame_canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)
        self.window_frame.bind('<Configure>', self.frame_size)
    def frame_size(self, event):
            size = (root.winfo_reqwidth(), root.winfo_reqheight())
            self.frame_canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 100, 100))
            # self.frame_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.window_frame.bbox('all'))
            self.frame_canvas.config(width=event.width, height=event.height)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to set the Canvas's `scrollregion` so that it knows how far the scrollbars are allowed to shift the contents.  Also, the scrollbars are normally siblings of the Canvas, not children of it - this is going to result in a bit of invisible content area at the right and bottom of the Canvas, where the scrollbars cover it up.

Comment: @jasonharper In fact,I had setted scrollregion, and also put scrollbar in root window at first, but it didn't work, so I changed it. but this still the bar still didn't show up.

Comment: *"the bar don't show up"*: This `.config(scrollregion=((0, 0, 100, 100))` must be greater than `Canvas(
..., width=..., height=`. [Edit] your Question and explain in detail your meaning of *"don't show up"* also show the values of  `i_window_width/height`.

Comment: @stovfl I did set the scrollregion greater than Canvas,
    self.frame_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.window_frame.bbox('all'))
above is what had I did,but it didn't work

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show  the result of `window_frame.bbox('all)'` and  the values of `i_window_width/height` to be a [mcve]. As it stands its `(0, 0, 0, 0)`, therefore, less than `(0, 0, 100, 100`, so **nothing** to scroll.

Comment: now, I got what's wrong is, like @stovfl said, the scrollregion is incorrect.

Comment: I don't konw why though, but the size of window_frame widget is alway (1,1) if I use     window_frame.winfo_reqwidth/reqheight. Is there any way to get correct size of frame?